# android startActivity not starting activity in accessibility service

Tags: android, android-service, accessibilityservice

I want to start an a third part activity when my Accessibility Service is connected. So I'm writing the below code in `onServiceConnected()` method

```
@Override
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                               IBinder service) {
    Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(THIRD_PARTY_APP_PACKAGE);
    if (launchIntent != null) {
        getApplicationContext().startActivity(launchIntent);
    }
}
```

The same code, when written inside onClick of a button in my application, works fine. I even debugged it to check whether the code is getting executed, and the line

```
getApplicationContext().startActivity(launchIntent);
```

executes without any exception but that app is not launched.

Also, when I try to open my own activity from the service like below, it doesn't work

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FormActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```

**EDIT**

I'm using Android 10

Answer (score 0):

you can startActivity directly in AccessibilityService,don't need to getApplicationContext and startActivity.

Comment: That itself was not working that's why I tried adding getApplicationContext()